# Migrating data from Oracle to SQL Server error: The value is Null

Tags: oracle, sql-server-migration-assi, sql-server-2017

I have been getting a strange error since today when trying to migrate data from an Oracle DB Server to SQL Server 2017 Express using the latest SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle v7.5

The error affects certain tables only and read simply: `The value is Null`

[image: During import process]

[image: Import report]

I don;t know how to trace the issue especially because it was working last week when I did the last import on an older version of SSMA. Just this morning the new version got installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using "Oracle Client Provider" to connect to Oracle and I was running into the same problem.

I switched to `OLEDB Provider` and `TNSNAME mode` just to test. That solved the problem for me!

Comment: I'll check that first thing tomorrow!

Comment: I got into the same issue and this solves the problem. But I will highly appreciate if anyone can explain why ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in SSMA v7.5, and has been fixed in version v7.6.